# Export in Crystal report to PDF only 75 files are exported out of 500 files using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pdf, datagridview, crystal-reports

I am exporting from Crystal Report to PDF. When I export to PDF, only 75 files out of 500 export. Please can any one help...

```
enter code here
//datagridview to crystal report        
DataSet ds = new DataSet();     
ds.Tables.Add(dt1);    
ds.WriteXmlSchema("sample.xml");   

//transefer data to crystalreportviewer    
CrystalReport11 cr = new CrystalReport11();   
cr.SetDataSource(ds);    
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;    
//datagridview to crystal report end    
//textbox to crystal report start    
cr.SetParameterValue("uniqueid", textBox1.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("Rev", textBox2.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("Date", textBox3.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("Status", textBox4.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("description", textBox5.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("Unit", textBox6.Text);    
cr.SetParameterValue("ProjectDocNo", textBox7.Text);     
//textbox to crystal report end  

// export to pdf start    
ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFile
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOpti
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "d:\\output\\" + pdfname +
CrExportOptions = cr.ExportOptions;
{
CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.Disk
CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFor
CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
}
cr.Export();
//export to pdf end
```

Comment: Please any one reply me..

Comment: there is a limitation for printing reports in crystal reports you can work around as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your report viewer page:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    cr.Close()
    cr.Dispose()
End Sub
```